# How much memory should my rails stack be consuming?

Tags: apache-2.2, memory, phusion-passenger, memory-usage

I am running my own webserver on a 384MB VPS from Slicehost to serve two Ruby on Rails applications on separate Virtual Hosts. I am running Phusion Passenger with Apache2. The following is the contents of my Passenger.conf

```
<IfModule passenger_module>

PassengerRoot /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.6-20090610/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.11
PassengerLogLevel 0
PassengerRuby /usr/local/bin/ruby
PassengerUserSwitching on
PassengerDefaultUser nobody
PassengerMaxPoolSize 3
PassengerMaxInstancesPerApp 2 
PassengerPoolIdleTime 300

# Ruby on Rails Options

RailsAutoDetect on
RailsSpawnMethod smart

NameVirtualHost *:80
</IfModule>
```

If i do a 'top' on my server I have 314MB used on average, this seems like too much? Am I mistaken and if not what possible steps can I take to reduce the Memory usage?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on the applications you are trying to host. The more models / controllers an application has the bigger the application will be. To get a better feel for how much the rails application itself is using try issuing the command.

```
passenger-memory-stats
```

My medium-sized application at this moment is using:

```
### Total private dirty RSS: 68.93 MB
```

According to passenger. If you have a bunch of sites running on the same passenger instance it could look more like:

```
### Total private dirty RSS: 1489.46 MB
```

Also consider that if you run a stock mysql-server the settings are not really optimized for VPS (and thus low memory) usage.

Comment: ### Total private dirty RSS: 79.12 MB

Comment: I do have 11 Apache processes running though it that normal?

Comment: Yeah that's possible, you can edit your apache.conf to make it use less proccesses. I would check out top and sort by memory usage to find out what's really using your memory.

Comment: Mem:    405612k total,   356656k used,    48956k free,    81848k buffers
Swap:   786424k total,    22832k used,   763592k free,    74124k cached

Comment: 16865 app_esta  20   0  269m  69m 2608 S    0 17.6   01.13 ruby                                                                                                                                                                                                             
16830 root      20   0 71684  16m 2552 S    0  4.1   00.18 ruby                                                                                                                                                                                                             
18138 www-data  20   0  100m  15m 5592 S    0  3.9   00.12 php